# Excel VBA code for copy and transpose

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA code for a simple copy and (paste) transpose row data and results looks like below

#### Row data

[image: Row data]

#### Final results

[image: final results]

Kindly help me.

Comment: I don't think that's a transpose, looks like de-normalisation to me.

Comment: Thanks. There are over 10000 rows like this. How can I convert my data as seen on final results image.

Comment: Ok, I have written some code for you ;)   see my answer.  Also I think you should edit title of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you accept answer and upvote 
Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()


    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion


    Dim dicMaster As Object
    Set dicMaster = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim lRowLoop As Long
    For lRowLoop = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        Dim vLeft As Variant
        vLeft = rng.Cells(lRowLoop, 1)

        Dim vRight As Variant
        vRight = rng.Cells(lRowLoop, 2)

        Dim dicSub As Object
        If Not dicMaster.exists(vLeft) Then
            Set dicSub = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dicMaster.Add vLeft, dicSub
        End If
        Set dicSub = dicMaster.Item(vLeft)

        dicSub.Add dicSub.Count, vRight

    Next

    '* find the widest
    Dim lWidest As Long
    lWidest = 0
    Dim vKeyLoop As Variant
    For Each vKeyLoop In dicMaster.Keys

        Dim lCount As Long
        lCount = dicMaster(vKeyLoop).Count
        If lWidest < lCount Then lWidest = lCount
    Next
    '* so now dimension results

    ReDim vResults(1 To dicMaster.Count, 1 To lWidest + 1) As Variant

    Dim lRowIndex As Long
    For Each vKeyLoop In dicMaster.Keys
        lRowIndex = lRowIndex + 1

        vResults(lRowIndex, 1) = vKeyLoop
        Set dicSub = dicMaster.Item(vKeyLoop)

        Dim lColIndex As Long
        lColIndex = 2

        Dim vItemLoop As Variant
        For Each vItemLoop In dicSub.Items
            vResults(lRowIndex, lColIndex) = vItemLoop
            lColIndex = lColIndex + 1
        Next vItemLoop

    Next

    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Resize(dicMaster.Count, lWidest + 1) = vResults

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice example of `Dictionary` use.