# How to copy and paste transpose using macro

Tags: vba

I am seeking for help I have thousands of unit ID that I need to copy and paste transpose manually. Here is the situation if column C Seq no. is the same for example Seq 1 then I need to copy column B unit ID and paste transpose to column D and I need to do that to the rest of the column

[image]

Comment: Did you try recording a macro whilst doing it? You could apply a filter on col C , then find the last row and then construct a range from Range("B2:B" & LastRow) and pass that to Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose. There are limits to transpose though. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit. This will help with transpose part [excel-vba-range-copy-transpose-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852717/excel-vba-range-copy-transpose-paste)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA code for copy and transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921479/excel-vba-code-for-copy-and-transpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub TransposeUnitID()
    Dim data As Variant, seq_number As Integer, rw as Long

    data = Range("B2:C21").Value '~~>Update as necessary
    seq_number = data(1, 2)
    rw = 2

    For i = 1 To UBound(data)

        If data(i, 2) <> seq_number Then
            seq_number = data(i, 2)
            rw = i + 1
        End If

        Range("B" & rw).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = data(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Notes:

- Reads your data in as an array
- Assume `Seq` is ordered (as per example)
- Loop over array and keep track of `Seq` to print `UnitID` to correct cell

Comment: @ alex P thank you so much this really helps i just want to ask how can i extend the range data = Range("B2:C99").Value tried to maximize to thousand but got error i want to extend on the whole column c

Comment: Just replace the range with Range(“B2:C99”).value.

Comment: Im getting error if i change to more than thousand Range(“B2:C1900”).value

Comment: It says run time error 1004: apllication- defined or object defined error

Comment: i got error on this line        Range("B" & rw).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = data(i, 1)

Comment: Can you debug the line to see what the issue is e.g. what is `rw` set to? The issue is likely to do with `rw` or `i` not being set to a valid value. Or if you have gaps in your data (e.g blank row) then `End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)` will fail...